# Can't resolve all parameters for Lightbox: ([object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], ?)

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular8, lightbox

> Can't resolve all parameters for Lightbox: ([object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], ?)

In **app.module.ts**

```
import { LightboxModule } from 'ngx-lightbox';

imports: [
    LightboxModule
  ]
```

the error seems like,

[image]

Comment: which version of ngx-lightbox are you using?

Comment: Check this:https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19417#issuecomment-413890638

Comment: version 3 @MKant